# Populating drop down list from a database in django

Tags: python, django

[Want to retrieve data from the database in this department ID field which is on another model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5de6.png)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score -1):

If you use **django model form** here is one way for it

i give the link for it go though this

[Model Choice Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using class based views.Send the department data through context data.
Or else you can use Choice field in forms.py